# how to get records from one column that is not in another column codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi i am using codeigniter , and i have a table like this

[image]

i want to get all records where `PreferenceID` value is not in `PreferenceParentID` column

in this case i am  fitering table  also with the `EntityID` .  and `PreferenceParentID` shoul be `!= 0`

suppose i filter by `entityID` `53`

my results shoul be

```
Couture , Denims
```

because `PreferenceID` is not in `PreferenceParentID` in both cases . i tried with `where_not_in()` but could not do . please help

this is my query

```
    $table = $this->mastables['shop_profile_preferences'];
    $this->db->select('a.ProfilePreferenceID');
    $this->db->from($table." as a");

    $where2 = "(SELECT a.PreferenceParentID FROM ".$table.")";
    $this->db->where_not_in('a.PreferenceID', $where2);

    $this->db->where("a.EntityID",$shop_id);
    $this->db->where('a.PreferenceParentID !=',0);

    $query=$this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

the result of my query is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePreferenceID] => 274
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePreferenceID] => 275
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ProfilePreferenceID] => 276
        )

)
```

how to use `where_not_in()` properly . or ids there any other methods . please help  .....
thanks in advance .

**UPDATE**

```
    $table = $this->mastables['shop_profile_preferences'];
    $this->db->select('a.ProfilePreferenceID,a.ProfilePreferenceValue');
    $this->db->from($table." as a");

    $this->db->where('a.PreferenceParentID !=',0);
    $this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT a.PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.')', NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->where("a.EntityID",$shop_id);

    $query=$this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with CodeIgniter's `where_not_in()`. Because the second argument is supposed to be an array and not a string like that.

What you can do is instead use the usual `where()` method.

```
$this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT a.PreferenceParentID FROM `table_name`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

In case you're wondering, the third argument in the code above is to prevent CodeIgniter from trying to protect the field and table name with backticks.

Comment: i changed my query to $this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT a.PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.')', NULL, FALSE);

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Can you update your post with the updated code?

Comment: hmm i have made a mistake . in my code $this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT a.PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.')', NULL, FALSE);
and it shoul be $this->db->where('a.PreferenceID NOT IN (SELECT PreferenceParentID FROM '.$table.')', NULL, FALSE);  . a.PreferenceParentID shoul be PreferenceParentID

Comment: Fantastic life saver! Thank you.